# Making a Minecraft resource pack in iOS

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m following [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_resource_pack_add-ons) tutorial to create a resource pack in BE. The guide assumes you are using a computer, but I was actually able to make one in iOS by creating the appropriate folders and json files, and moving them to the appropriate Minecraft directory via the files app.  I can even see my pack on the ”more packs” list when I go to add a resource pack to my new world. Everything worked smoothly in the tutorial up to [the very last step](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_resource_pack_add-ons#Testing_our_Resource_Pack) when I tried to test it and add the pack to my world.

When I try to *add* the pack to my new world, I get a loading message “Connecting to marketplace...” which then terminates shortly after and returns back to my world creation screen without adding it. I am guessing it is looking for this pack somewhere on the marketplace, but can’t find it? Is there any way to fix this or get around it?

As an afternote, here is an image of my “Tutorial Resource Pack” in the list of packs. The aforementioned loading message appears after pressing the plus button.
[image]

Comment: What last step exactly, and could you summarize that step here? I assume it's [this one](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_resource_pack_add-ons#Testing_our_Pack), but it would clarify your question if you told us the exact moment things go awry.

Comment: Added to the question @Joachim

Comment: It's better to write it out in your question, so it is self-contained.

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a mcpack file and importing it?

Comment: @cherryblossom I discovered a second directory. One for premium content, one for owned content I believe. Moved it to my owned content directory and it adds just fine now. However, my pack still doesn’t appear to change any textures in game. That could be a different question on its own...